# psql: ForeignKey constraint name

Tags: postgresql, django-models, foreign-keys

I am working with django and postgresql. While looking in psql to see the database and table schema, I noticed that most of the times the Foreign-key constraints are named as `modelname__field_id_hexnum_fk_basemodel_field_id` but in some cases it is a hash e.g.  `D19cb71bc44206c3464da32ad943c8f8`. Why does this happen? Is it because of the length of the constraint name or some other factors causes this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe same logic as many-to-many relationship intermediary join table?..

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/

> Behind the scenes, Django creates an intermediary join table to
>   represent the many-to-many relationship. By default, this table name
>   is generated using the name of the many-to-many field and the name of
>   the table for the model that contains it. Since some databases don’t
>   support table names above a certain length, these table names will be
>   automatically truncated to 64 characters and a uniqueness hash will be
>   used.